# C Scope and Memory usage

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a question concerning scope and how memory is handled in C. Example:

```c
int main(){
    int some,
        instance,
        variables;
    
    { // scoped block to do some work
        int more,
            data,
            just,
            forThisBlock;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Essentially my question is this.... Does it make sense to use a block as above to section off areas to instantiate temporarily used data? Memory-wise, what happens to the variables allocated in the block? Are they de-allocated after the block exits, ostensibly saving memory further on in the function? I realize a proper function could also serve the purpose, but in some cases adding another function is not as neat if the work is only a couple lines long.

#### Edit: my particular use case:

Many functions return an int to show if an error occurred or not. I have noticed from looking around that a style convention is to 'pile' variable declarations at the beginning of their scope block. If you have a few of these function uses, then you could potentially cloud up the declarations with the variables to store these return values (or really any variable that is only used temporarily, and the processing of which requires many of the other more 'permanent' variables that would make a for a long function declaration). Essentially the purpose of the question is determining the ramifications of scoping off these usages to attempt a cleaner look and declaration section. I realize for some cases one could reuse this return value, but the purpose of this question is to better understand my options.

For example:

```c
    int infoRtn;
    char *serverHost;
    ...    


    infoRtn = getaddrinfo(
            serverHost,
            port,
            &addrCriteria,
            &addrList
    );

    if(infoRtn != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s @ %d: Failed to get address info, error returned: %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, infoRtn);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    ...
```

vs

```c
    char *serverHost;
    ...    

    {
        int infoRtn = getaddrinfo(
                serverHost,
                port,
                &addrCriteria,
                &addrList
        );
    
        if(infoRtn != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s @ %d: Failed to get address info, error returned: %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, infoRtn);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    ...
```

Comment: The compiler may or may not re-use the memory.

Comment: The memory is "allocated" by adjusting the stack pointer. This almost certainly doesn't lead to any visible increase in "memory usage" for any meaning of the term.

Comment: Are you concerned about the performance?  Normally compilers are great , don't worry to much until you benchmark it.

Comment: More of just trying to understand the specifics and rammifications of certain syntax @user202729 . I realize it is a nitpick and probably not something that would matter terribly in the scheme of things :)

Comment: Good modern compilers perform lifetime analysis and optimize memory use based on where you assign and use values, regardless of whether they are in nested scopes or not. So nested scopes are largely irrelevant for saving memory. They are useful for grouping code and limiting scopes of identifiers. For example, if you define a temporary variable inside one compound statement, you cannot accidentally use it in another. So they help avoid errors.

Comment: I commonly use compound statements when the first and/or last iteration of some loop needs special processing. Having a compound statement before and after the main loop results in the “first iteration” and “last iteration” having the same indentation and conveying the similarity to the main loop body, as well as isolating identifiers used only in the iteration code. It can also be used to set off small sequence of code where you need a temporary variable to compute something but it is not big enough to warrant a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to use a block as above to section off areas to instantiate temporarily used data?

Personally I haven't seen many use cases of having anonymous blocks to do something.
Functions are designed for that and you should use it, Using functions also gives visibility that you are trying to do something (but hides its implementation) and is better for readability eg

```
int averagreMarks = getAvgMarks(students);
```

Here when I read I see average marks of students are requested. If I want to see its implementation I go and see else I just skip over to main logic (Better readability)

> Memory-wise, what happens to the variables allocated in the block

Yes they are destroyed (at least in most C compilers) so memory wise it can be analogous to a function but I would strongly urge to use functions for better readability and maintainability

**EDIT (After details got added to question)**

I propose a 3rd solution to this

```
 {
    char *serverHost;
    validateConnection() //Add params that you want to send
    ...    

    }
    
validateConnection() {
    int infoRtn;
    infoRtn = getaddrinfo(
            serverHost,
            port,
            &addrCriteria,
            &addrList
    );

    if(infoRtn != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s @ %d: Failed to get address info, error returned: %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, infoRtn);
        exit(1);
}
```

The above solution has advantage that user knows ok now we do validate and continue. Plus in future if your validate logic is modified (example you add retries) you dont clutter the original function.

Comment: Interesting, but seem to be at odds with some of the comments, like with @0___________ 
+1 for promoting clean code, though I have updated my question to show a potential use case